# Node.js: Referencing custom class within another custom class

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I'm writing a web backend that has a User class.  It also has an Attributes class which records user stats.  However, I'm unsure how to reference the Attributes class within the User.js file.  I'd want to be able to do this, more or less:

```
function User(id){
    this.attributes = new Attributes();
}

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to call the other module...

```
var Attributes = require('/path/to/attributes.js')

function User (id) {
  this.id = id
  this.attributes = new Attributes()
}

module.exports = User
```

If you want to extend `User`

```
var Attributes = require('/path/to/attributes.js')

function User (id) {
  this.id = id
}

User.prototype = Object.create(Attributes.prototype);
User.prototype.constructor = Attributes;

module.exports = User
```

Now whatever methods `Attributes` has `User` will have, and you can do `user instanceof Attributes`

Comment: So how would this work if I, say, use the User class in a file that has already included the Attributes class?  Would node just ignore the second require, or is that require local to that file?

Comment: it would be required once and then just referenced after that point as it is already in memory -- more here -- http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles